# Where can I find the files list displaying all files that have been set `assume-unchanged`?

Tags: git

Git has a function to ignore a changed file when you pull from remote repository. That's [git update-index --assume-unchanged yourFileName](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index). I just want to know how can I know that whether a file has been set with this flag. However there is nothing I can find in google.

Comment: Incidentally, this doesn't actually mean "ignore a changed file". To do that reliably, you need to set the `--skip-worktree` bit. The `--assume-unchanged` bit tells Git that it does not need to check whether the file is changed, but Git might, accidentally or on purpose, check anyway. (In practice they seem to work the same, it's just that the skip-worktree bit is documented as being more what you want here.)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_using_assume_unchanged_bit):

> To see which files have the "assume unchanged" bit set, use `git ls-files -v`

Where in `-v` stands for:

> Similar to `-t`, but use lowercase letters for files that are marked as assume unchanged.

Therefore the lowercase letter in front of the file name will indicate that this file is marked as "assume unchanged". `git-ls-files` also accepts file name as an argument, so you could use it as follows:

```
git ls-files -v <file-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

These bits can only be seen, as far as I know, with the `--debug` and `-v` flags of `git ls-files`.  The output for `--debug` is deliberately not very well documented, while the output for `-v` is linked with that for `-t` which is called "semi-deprecated".

I set the assume-unchanged flag on `wt-status.c` and the skip-worktree flags on `wt-status.h` in a Git repository for Git.  Here's a bit of `git ls-files` output, with various flags; the assume-unchanged flag, set on `wt-status.c`, is `0x8000`:

```
$ git ls-files --debug
...
wt-status.c
  ctime: 1479501926:0
  mtime: 1479501926:0
  dev: 127  ino: 11320057
  uid: 1001 gid: 1001
  size: 63601   flags: 8000
wt-status.h
  ctime: 1479501926:0
  mtime: 1479501926:0
  dev: 127  ino: 11320058
  uid: 1001 gid: 1001
  size: 3534    flags: 40004000
```

As you can see here, `wt-status.h` (with skip-worktree set) has flags `0x40004000`, which are:

```
#define CE_EXTENDED  (0x4000)
#define CE_SKIP_WORKTREE     (1 << 30)
```

(I skipped inapplicable flags here: they run from `0x3000`, which are the stage number mask, through `1 << 31`.  Some appear to be used in-core only and some are saved in the actual on-disk index.)

Attempting to set *both* `assume-unchanged` *and* `--skip-worktree` works, but must be done in two steps:

```
$ git update-index --assume-unchanged ws.c
$ git update-index --skip-worktree ws.c
$ git ls-files --debug -- ws.c
ws.c
  ctime: 1451486045:0
  mtime: 1451486045:0
  dev: 127  ino: 11319929
  uid: 1001 gid: 1001
  size: 9782    flags: 4000c000
```

(attempting to set both at once just set one of them).  Here's how `git ls-files -v` shows them:

```
$ git ls-files -v -- ws.c wt-status.c wt-status.h xdiff-interface.h
s ws.c
h wt-status.c
S wt-status.h
H xdiff-interface.h
```

(I included an extra file, with no flags set, to show how that gets displayed here: the `H` indicates that it's in the cache.  This is of course necessarily true for any file that has a bit set in the cache.  That should include files marked for deletion [`CE_REMOVE_WT` or `1 << 22`] though `git ls-files` won't show them, even with `--deleted`, which seems like a bug.)